# Content container not resizing to fit content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out; http://nicklemmon.com/lily

For some reason the height of the .content div won't adjust to fit its contents! I can make the height of .content greater than 100%, but that kind of defeats the purpose of a fluid layout. This is just a random site I was working on to learn more about CSS animations, yet I've run in to this silly barrier on the way.

Help!

Comment: It's because you have 100vh

Comment: img does not EVER have a closing tag. The img class should be img-responsive img-circle the inline style should be removed. The tag for this question should be twitter-bootstrap-3 NOT bootstrap (which is something entirely different). Leave the height alone, don't fool with it (I see you fixed it).

Comment: Open up both your main site and the sample in Firefox, the stuff in red should be fixed. Or use developer tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `height` of `100vh`, remove it and you should be fine.

## Update(making left column height equal to right column height)

As it appears, there seems to be no straightforward way to adjust left column to same height as right column using pure CSS, you can do a workaround in a number of different ways, best way I would suggest is to use `Javascript/jQuery`.

```
//HTML
<div class="moving-right big-lefty col-md-3">

</div>
<div class="big-righty col-md-9">

</div>

//jQuery to use on document ready.
$(".big-lefty").height($(".big-righty").height());
```

you might want to try another CSS solution that did not work in your case when I tried it on chrome, using inspector. you might want to play with it.

Have `.content` as `display:table-row` and `.big-lefty` and `big-righty` as `display:table-cell`

Comment: Hmm, that seems to have worked. How would I make the left column height match the height of .content?

Comment: Use something to equalize the heights to match the height. I use jQuery but others do all kinds of stuff. In your case look for the padding-bottom negative margin approach as it should work. Read my comment in the OP

Comment: Your little jQuery snippet worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`overflow:auto` should do the trick for you.

```
.content{
    overflow:auto;
}
```